# Make Font Awesome icons in a circle?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using font awesome on some project but I have some things that I want to do with font awesome icons, I can easily call an icon like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
```

Is it possible to all icon always be in round circle with border? Something like this, I have a picture:

[image]

Using

```
i {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Will do the effect, but the problem is that icons are always bigger that the text or element beside, any solutions?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```css
i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888;
  padding: 0.5em 0.6em;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
```

---

JsFiddle of old answer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4LqeN/

Comment: Got sometning, but not round circle?

Comment: The `border-radius` should round the element. What brower do you use?  will updated my answer with prefixes

Comment: But this is not a solution. This only works if the `i` has content. Usually with FA you don't have content within the i-tag, but the icon is rendered by CSS later: `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>` and this is what @Schneider actually asked for.

Comment: @Jan I will investigate in that tomorrow. But i can not see a Problem. You are Right, that the tags don't have content, but the content will be added via css. Even when the Icon would fail to load, you would see an circle. Can you make a jsFiddle of a Problem you see with the answer?

Comment: Here you can see it in action:http://fiddle.jshell.net/4LqeN/275/ you will still Need to alter the line height and padding, but it Works. Your concern is not valid and the answer is correct.

Comment: does not scale right with the fontawesome size because you define a static radius when the icon is dynamic size, my test shows a fa-lg being in an oval, not a circle.

Comment: No. This is the answer to the question. See the images of the question. There is a shadow, not a hard circle.

Comment: I will just add, to have a perfect circle, use 50% value of border radius :)

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 275):

With Font Awesome you can easily use stacked icons like this:

UPDATE: Font Awesome v6.2.1

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fa-thin fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-lock fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

UPDATE: Font Awesome v5.15.4

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fal fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-lock fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

refer [Font Awesome Stacked Icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons)

Update:-
Fiddle for [stacked icons](http://jsfiddle.net/sampatbadhe/ocftsLfe/)

Comment: The stacked icons only work up till 2x. If you want larger than that, it doesn't work

Comment: @JLee I have added Fiddle for larger icons.
see this for larger icons http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#larger

Comment: wish this was the accepted answer, its the "correct" way to do this with fontawesome. Accepted answer is a hack that does not adjust well.

Comment: Same with numbers `<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">1</i>
            </span>`

Comment: @gcphost you are right but also this way is not the precise way either.

Comment: @emrah - its the only option here that is truely fontawesome, not custom css, so its more precise then anything here.

Comment: problem for this stacked icon, you cant put a background on circle,

Comment: Very elegant solution. @mmativ if you mean a background color on the circle you simply do <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x" style="color:blue"></i>

Comment: for FontAwesome 5.2 try:       <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>

Comment: @SampatBadhe I'm using v5.8.1 of font awesome. This doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mike Can you please create Fiddle so that I can look into it. 

classes might be different in newer versions. 

`<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fas fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i> </span>` can you check with this snippet posted by @qu1ckdry

Comment: How would you do this with react font-awesome?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native Could you look into this?

Comment: YOU DA MAN! Elegant solution. This is how it was meant to be.

Answer (score 48):

You don't need css or html tricks for it.
Font Awesome has built in class for it -  **fa-circle** To stack multiple icons together you can use fa-stack class on the parent div

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

//And we have now facebook icon inside circle:)

Comment: Sampat Badhe has told in his answer the same more than 2 years ago. Why dont  you read other answers before writing yours?

Comment: hey, sorry for Sampat, i didn't see him answer, i'll try to modify my answer and add more solutions or helpful info.

Comment: It is a good solution, but it gives a blue background to each of the icon. Any work around ?

Comment: @CodeIt Just use css to clear it or add new background color. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 34):

### Font icon in a circle using `em` as the base measurement

if you use ems for the measurements, including `line-height`, `font-size` and `border-radius`, with `text-align: center` it makes things pretty solid:

```
#info i {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  width: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.8em; /* or 50% width & line-height */
}
```

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 15):

**Update:** Rather use flex.

If you want precision this is the way to go.

Fiddle. Go Play -> http://jsfiddle.net/atilkan/zxjcrhga/

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="sosial-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.sosial-links a{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #909090;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 7px; /*space between*/

} 
.sosial-links a i{
    padding: 12px 11px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #909090;
}
```

NOTE: Don't use this anymore. Use flexbox.

Comment: adding text-align:center; Makes it work with pretty much everything even fa-info

Comment: how about vertical align?

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this. I wanted to add a circle around my icomoon icons. Here is the code.

```
span {
font-size: 54px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 10px solid rgb(205, 209, 215);
padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**:

Upon learning flex recently, there is a cleaner way (no tables and less css). Set the wrapper as `display: flex;` and to center it's children give it the properties `align-items: center;` for (vertical) and `justify-content: center;` (horizontal) centering.

See this [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mfbvb35/)

---

Strange that nobody suggested this before.. I always use tables to do this.
Simply make a wrapper have `display: table` and center stuff inside it with `text-align: center` for horizontal and `vertical-align: middle` for vertical alignment.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <i class='icon fa fa-bars'></i>
</div>
```

and some sass like this

```
.wrapper{
  display: table; 

  i{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }

}
```

or see this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bchr4444/)

Comment: This ist a very nice and clean and small one! 
Heres a fiddle with CSS instead of SCSS 
https://jsfiddle.net/bqtkmy0s/

Comment: @summsel isn't this the **exact** same thing as my original answer? You just wrote the code in scss and not css.

Comment: yes, of course it is. I tried your solution in css and there are plenty of people out there prefering css. So why not post the jsfiddle of this css-version.

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Comment: This is easiest solution and should have been accepted answer, as this doesn't need to add new elements as shown in accepted or highest voted answer.  This answer follow KISS technique very well.

Answer (score 7):

This is the approach you don't need to use `padding`, just set the `height` and `width` for the `a` and let the `flex` handle with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.social-links a{
  text-align:center;
 float: left;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 border: 2px solid #909090;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin-right: 7px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
} 
.social-links a i{
 font-size: 20px;
    align-self:center;
 color: #909090;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-links a i::before{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.social-links a:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.social-links a:hover i{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="social-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 4):

The below example didnt quite work for me,this is the version that i made work!

HTML:

```
<div class="social-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-links {
    text-align:center;
}

.social-links a{
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #909090;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;

}
.social-links a i{
    padding: 18px 11px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #909090;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-2x-circle"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i></div>
```

CSS:

```
i {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.icon-2x-circle {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome icons are inserted as a :before. Therefore you can style either your **i** or **a** like so:

```
.i {
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;   
   width: 20px;
}

<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
```

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get round icon using this code:

```
<a class="facebook-share-button social-icons" href="#" target="_blank">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook socialicons"></i>
</a>
```

Now your CSS will be:

```
.social-icons {
display: inline-block;border-radius: 25px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
padding: 0.5em;
background: #0D47A1;
font-size: 20px;
}
.socialicons{color: white;}
```

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I like Dave Everitt's answer with the « line-height » but it only works by specifying the « height » and then we have to add « !important » to line-height ...

```
.cercle {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em!important;
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

Comment: The line-height was solving it for me

Comment: Adding `!important` is a band-aid, not a solution. It means you have another CSS property somewhere else overriding your property.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and most precise solution I've found so far.

CSS:

```
.social .fa {
      margin-right: 1rem;
      border: 2px #fff solid;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this CSS class -

```
.i{
    display: flex;
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: #888;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This will get your work done