# How can i add a circular backgrounds around a react icon?

Tags: reactjs, components, icons

How can I add circular backgrounds around icons? I currently have an icon from react-icons and would like to add a circle around it. But so far some of my methods have not worked. Any input is valued.

below is the approach and thank you.

```
import { RiRocketLine } from 'react-icons/ri'
....
<div id='icons' className='icon'>
   <RiRocketLine style={{ color: 'red' }} size="30px" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `border-radius` and `border`

I used plain html, but the answer will not differ for react

```css
.icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon"></span>
```

Comment: so instead of a div use a span?

Comment: The tag doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: You can change the div border-radius by 50%  and adjust the position of your icon, I hope it will work for you.

```
#icons{
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

import { RiRocketLine } from 'react-icons/ri'
....
<div id='icons' className='icon'>
   <RiRocketLine style={{ color: 'red' }} size="30px" />
</div>
```

you can check this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905710/make-font-awesome-icons-in-a-circle)